# Submit post Data (Without change HTML input) after serialized and changing on Submit() Event

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form with three input fields

```
<form action="Action" method="Post Or Get">
<input name="in1" value="1"/><br/>
<input name="in2" value="2"/><br/>
<input name="in3" value="3"/><br/>
</form>
```

On Submit action I want to change post data without changing the input values, like this:

```
 $("form").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
     var values, index;
     values = $(this).serializeArray();

        for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) 
          values[index].value = "new value.."; /// change All Data Values without change Input Value


       ///I  need to Submit this New Form Data     

        this.submit();
    });
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What is the reason using `serializeArray();` for the input data?

Comment: you don't need `.value` here `values[index].value`, also you may need to use ajax, will that be ok for you?

Comment: i use serializeArray to get Array of name and value to help me to controller each value

Comment: @AminJafari in my case i dont need Ajax

Comment: I think it isn't possible to change the values in you html form. I assume the browser reads the data first, then the submit function is called.

Comment: maybe is correct your opinion !!